# "~that is seen as an example or a rule to be followed~"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-structure

This is [the definition of the word 'precedent' in Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/precedent?q=precedent%20).

> **precedent** *noun*: [countable, uncountable] an official action or decision that has
> happened in the past and that is seen as an example **or** a rule to be
> followed in a similar situation later
>
> *The ruling set a precedent for future libel cases.*

I think the 'or' in bold should be changed to 'of' because a precedent could be an example of a rule to be handed down in the future.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A precedent can be either:

1. An example, something that is persuasive but need not be followd: *There is precedent for a nation ignoring an economic attack*
2. A rule to be folloed, binding on the current situation: *The Controllign precedant on what constitutes incitemetn is* Brandenburg v Ohio.  *That case introduced the "imminent lawless action" test.

A precedent is not normally spoken of as an "example of a rule". It is either an example or a rule.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If I rewrite 'an example or a rule to be followed in a similar situation later' as 'an example of a ruling that follows in a similar situation later', would it be natural?

Comment: That is grammatical, but it does not have the same meaning. "A  ruling  that **follows**" is one that is derived or deduced from the current situation. "A rule **to be followed**"  is a guide to action that governs a current or future situation. Also a "ruling" is a specific decision, usually from a court or other authority (an umpire can make a ruling in a game), whil;e a "rule" may be the result of a ruling, it acts like a law. it spells out what is to be done.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The definition from the dictionary is fine.  If you split it into two, it would be clear:

1

> an official action or decision that has happened in the past and that is seen as an example to be followed in a similar situation later

2

> an official action or decision that has happened in the past and that is seen as a rule to be followed in a similar situation later

Your proposed change is also fine, but I do not see a necessity for such a change.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I disagree with the way you have split the definition. When a precedent is an **exam,ple** it is something that was done in the past, that may or may not be imitates now. When it is a **rule** then it is to be followed, it governs current or future action in any similar situation.